# call handler in another project in same solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, handlers

how can I call a generic handler defined in the same solution but different project?
the problem is that I will create a circular reference if I refer to that handler class?

Comment: Why would this create a circular reference? Do you have any code?

Comment: because the project with the handler already references the 'calling' project. Do i need to use a web service here?

Comment: I would suggest layering your code differently to eliminate the circular reference.

Comment: if you call the handler by path, meaning that you connect to the url, you do not need to reference it at project level. Or explain more what you have, why do you need to call the http handler class directly? Can't you refactor and put common code to be shared in a lower level class/project?